# Using bayes theorem in python to sovles probability of finding d

Tags: python, python-2.7, bayesian

i have a 10 x 10 grid. and a object1 and object2 that is randomly place in the grid. the prior probability that it can be place in any square is 0.01 (I believe). i am trying to find p(d|x,y) where d = the distance object2 is from object1 and x,y in a possible position of object1

[Full Code](http://ideone.com/GwW0tr)

```
def p_d_cond_w(self, d, x, y):



    # fill in probability p(d|x,y) of finding a distance d if x,y
    # is the position of the obj1. Note that obj2 has access to
    # its own position via self.x and self.y
```

I know the code doesnt compile. im just cant work out how to implement bayes theorem in the code.

Comment: You have to introduce first a metric to define the distance between two points on this grid. Once you have done this you have to loop over all points and measure the distance to (self.x, self.y). The point here is to show that once you are in the corner p(1,...) will be smaller than p(1,...) in the middle of the grid as there are more points closer to the point in the middle

Comment: is that not the function at the top of the code? `def dist(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return int(math.sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)) # L_2`

Comment: Oh, that's indeed a feasible metric. I am surprised it's Euclidean, L1 would have been simpler in this case. Anyway, no find all points that are exactly of distance d to (x,y)

Comment: It's bad style to have two class definitions here... Use one class or better don't use any class for this kind of problem...

Comment: @tschm This is the template we were given.

Comment: @tschm how do i work of the distance of all the points if the x,y values for both objects are random?

Comment: @goosingout, you have a 10x10 grid. There are only 100 possible points. Calculate the distance and probability for each of them given the fixed x and y values.

Comment: @senderle how would i go about doing that. i can work out the distance of the two objects. `dist(self.x, self.y, obj1.x, obj1.y)` but i dont know how to work out the new probabilities for each point

Comment: I don't understand your question. You don't have to _work out_ the probabilities at all. They're given to you in the full code you posted.

Comment: This is really more of a math question than a programming question.  Your function takes distance d, x, and y.  You need to find all of the points that are that distance away from (x,y), and sum up the probabilities of landing on any of those points.  

If d = 11, then probability = 0 because that's outside the grid no matter what (x,y) is (I'm assuming the grid spacing is 1 unit).  If d = 0, there is exactly one point at that distance, so the probability is just `p_w[x,y]`.  If d = 1, and (x,y) is in the middle, then `p_d_cond_w = p_w[x,y+1]+p_w[x,y-1]+p_w[x+1,y]+p_w[x-1,y]`.

Comment: So in general just loop over all the points, find the ones that are the given distance, and sum up the probabilities.